# Rails 4 form_for error: undefined method `model_name' for ActionController::Parameters:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a basic form for creating a user record:

```
<%= debug(@user) %>
<%= form_for @user, url: {action: "create_user"}, html: {class: "user-create-form"} do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group"><%= f.text_field :first_name, class:'form-control' %></div>
    <div class="form-group"><%= f.text_field :last_name, class:'form-control' %></div>
    <div class="form-group"><%= f.text_field :email, class:'form-control' %></div>
    <div class="form-group"><%= f.text_field :password, class:'form-control' %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller:

```
  def create_user
    @user = params[:user]
    @user = User.new if !@user
  end
```

This loads fine and without error, but when I submit the form, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin#create_user

Showing /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clippo2/app/views/admin/create_user.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for ActionController::Parameters:Class

Extracted source (around line #6):
  <%= form_for @user, url: {action: "create_user"}, html: {class: "user-create-form"} do |f| %>
```

Here's my routes:

```
  get "admin", to: "admin#index"
  get "admin/edit_user/:id", to: "admin#edit_user"
  patch "admin/edit_user/:id", to: "admin#edit_user"
  get "admin/create_user"
  post "admin/create_user"
  get "admin/delete_user"
  get "access/login"
  get "access/logout"
  post "access/attempt_login"

  root :to => 'pages#home'
```

Comment: can you paste your routes code.

Comment: Just added them to the question

Comment: Try changing `@user` to `:user` in your view (i.e. `form_for :user (...)`

Comment: @zrl3dx I tried that and there is no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Extracted source (around line #6):
  <%= form_for @user, url: {action: "create_user"}, html: {class: "user-create-form"} do |f| %>
```

`form_for` accepts object of `ActiveRecord` class. But you have made a mistake in controller in `create_user` action.

@user variable in `create_user` action is not an object of `active_record` because you are assigning `params[:user]` hash to that.

Change your code like this:

```
def create_user
  @user = User.new
end
```

Comment: That worked! But I had to make one change to user the strong parameters callback instead of params[:user] in `User.new(params[:user])`. Two quick questions. 1. Is my mistake specific to Rails 4? 2. Is it necessary to check params && params[:user]? Doesn't the latter entail the former?

Comment: 1. Rails 4 specific is only strong parameters but not the code. 2. You can avoid first one, i will edit the answer but why you need to check params[:user], are u sending request to this action via some other form as well(any special reason for checking params) ?

Comment: @AmanGarg see my answer. He is wrongly setting `create_user` route as both `get` and `post`, when he should be using `get new_user`, `post create_user`.

Comment: @AmanGarg I didn't want to throw errors when the page first loads (before any data is submitted).

Comment: @Emerson see my answer. You're routes are wrong and that's why you're receiving errors.

Comment: @Emerson: ok so, you are using the same action for initialize and creating user record, it is ok then, but better is to use crud operations. I have updating my code.

Comment: @Zenph: Your points are correct, i have suggested him to fix the bug in his code. Using namespaces and resourceful routes is better, he can change his code if he wants that way.

Comment: @Emerson: you don't need to check params[:user] presence. Even if it is nil, it will not throw error and will initialize a new User class object.

Answer (score 0):

The `create_user` requires `params[:user']` to function and so there is no need to check for params. A simple modification:

```
def create_user
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
end
```

Why would you then pass `User.new` if params are not present? `create_user` should be a post only route. You require `User.new(params[:user])` because if validation fails, you'll pass that object back to the form with errors and existing input.

Change your routes here:

```
  get "admin/create_user" => get "admin/new_user"
```

Then create a new method in your controller for `new_user`:

```
def new_user
  @user = User.new
end
```

You're also building your routes in the wrong way. Use resources:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :user
end
```

See [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information.